# Binary operator += cannot be applied to operands of the type

Tags: swift, xcode7.2

I have this error:

> Binary operator += cannot be applied to operands of the type.

How can I fix?

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "item" {
        inItem = false
        objects += object
    }
}
```

I have this error on line `objects += object`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Since you didn't show us the declarations of `objects` or `object`, and you didn't paste the complete error message (which should have included both types), it's difficult to help you. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I am really curious as to why you did remove pretty much the only helpful information from the error message.

Comment: Any responses to my answer? If it helped you, you can accept it. If it is still unclear, add comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are taking the sum of `objects` with `object` and there is no function for this operation.

To use any operator (`+=` is an operator) you need to declare functions for it. These are global functions. Which means they are not put inside the Type they work on. Under it is fine.

---

This is just a Type with some properties.

```
class MyType {

    var myInt : Int = 0
    var myString : String = ""
    var myFloat : Float = 0

    init(int: Int, string: String, float: Float) {
        myInt = int
        myString = string
        myFloat = float
    }
}
```

---

These are functions for the operators.

The first one is just a `+`, it returns a new instance of `MyType`
Notice how you need to combine all properties for which this makes sense. 
As an example I did not take the sum of `myFloat`, only the other properties.

```
func +(lhs:MyType,rhs:MyType) -> MyType {
    let intSum = lhs.myInt + rhs.myInt
    let stringSum = lhs.myString + rhs.myString
    return MyType(int: intSum, string: stringSum,float: lhs.myFloat)
}
```

The second one uses `inout` to alter the left hand side instance (lhs). There is no `return` in this function. Since the left hand side instance is updated.

```
func +=(inout lhs:MyType, rhs:MyType) {
    lhs.myInt += rhs.myInt
    lhs.myString += rhs.myString
}
```

Notice how these functions expect two parameters of the same Type. If `objects` and `object` are not of the same type (I am guessing one might be and `Array` or `Dictionairy`) then you need to create a function to take the sum of two unrelated Types.

---

This is another Type

```
class MyOtherType {

    var myDouble : Double = 0

}
```

---

This function uses the operator to take the sum of two otherwise unrelated Types

```
func +(lhs:MyType,rhs:MyOtherType) -> MyType {
    let floatSum = lhs.myFloat + Float(rhs.myDouble)
    return MyType(int: lhs.myInt, string: lhs.myString, float: floatSum)
}
```

---

**Some tests**

If you do not write the operator function you will get this:

```
let alpha = MyType(int: 20, string: "hello ", float: 0.5)
let beta = MyType(int: 22, string: "world", float: 0.75)
let delta = alpha + beta // error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'MyType' operands
```

If you do:

```
let alpha = MyType(int: 20, string: "hello ", float: 0.5)
let beta = MyType(int: 22, string: "world", float: 0.75)
let delta = alpha + beta // 42, "hello world", 0.5
```

If you do not write the operator function to take the sum with `MyOtherType`:

```
let alpha = MyType(int: 20, string: "hello ", float: 0.5)
let beta = MyOtherType()
let delta = alpha + beta // error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MyType' and 'MyOtherType'
```

---

It is important to include both the Type and declaration of `objects` and `object` in your question. Also, always copy the full error message, which should like something like this:

**error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MyType' and 'MyOtherType'**

---

If `objects` is an `Array` your sum function would look like this :

```
func +=<T where T : _ArrayType>(inout lhs:T, rhs:T.Generator.Element) {
    lhs.append(rhs)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand :(

Comment: @MicheleColadangelo updated, if you do not understand, please explain what you do not understand.